# Upload my package

Tags: linux

I created an python script with `argparse`, and I want to upload it to linux package manager, that users can download it with `apt-get`, where can I find anything about it ?

I asked google and I can't find anything about it, but anything.

Answer (score 3):

The specific procedure changes for each distro. Assuming you are using Ubuntu the I´m feeling lucky button in google returned me: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages.

You can submit your package to the [MOTU](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU) (Masters Of The Universe) Team. Each category of package has a specific master which you can find on a list in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~motu)

Comment: Depending on the stability/popularity of your package, it might also make sense to package on PyPi so folks could install via `pip`. See their packaging guidelines here: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/